# Retired gentleman that solves people's problems

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I believe this started as a TV movie (circa 1980's) and segued into a short-lived series.

The protagonist was a retired gentleman who took up lost causes from people who could not afford outside help. The principal actor reminds me of [Michael Caine](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000323) but I've checked that BIO backwards and forwards and it is not him. If there was an original TV movie, the principal character was a retired machinist¹. I don't use the term 'gentleman' lightly; the principal character could be considered the embodiment of a modern-day 'knight of the round table'.

I've done my own research on this but I keep getting caught up on the fact that I remember the original title as the 'The Expeditor' (which is wrong). It may be something similar or I could be completely off-track.

---

¹ <sub>After some more research fueled by [swstephe](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/25744/swstephe)'s answer, I believe my tiny little brain had mashed up the [Equalizer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088513/) series with a 1988 TV movie called [The Child Saver](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094861/) starring [Martin Balsam](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000842/) who played a retired machinist in a simlar role. Don't do drugs kids.</sub>

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My guess is [The Equalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Equalizer)

> The Equalizer is an American crime drama television series, originally
>   airing on CBS from fall 1985 until late-spring 1989. It starred Edward
>   Woodward as a retired espionage/intelligence officer with a mysterious
>   past, who uses the skills from his former career to exact vigilante
>   justice on behalf of innocent people who are hopelessly trapped in
>   dangerous circumstances. The series combined elements of the spy film,
>   private investigator/police procedural drama, and vigilante genres.

[image: Edward Woodward as 'The Equalizer']

Comment: Yeah, this is totally The Equalizer

Comment: Agreed! Thank you for helping me over my mental block.

Comment: They also made a movie starring Denzel Washington with the same name and premise as the T.V. show. It might be something to check out as well (I personally found the movie very good).